# Transition with Hero not working

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I'm using [the Hero library](https://github.com/lkzhao/Hero) to do a transition between view controllers.

First view controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var people = [Person]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        hero.isEnabled = true
        hero.modalAnimationType = .push(direction: .right)

    }

    @IBAction func handleButton(){
        let view = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondVC") as! UIViewController
        present(view, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Second view controller:

```
class Second: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        hero.isEnabled = true
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    @IBAction func handleBackButton(){
        hero.modalAnimationType = .push(direction: .left)
        hero.dismissViewController()
    }
}
```

It presents the new view without any animation. When I dismiss the second controller, it will apply the correct animation. How do I present the second view with an animation?

Comment: What is the pod command for installing Hero? I have used pod "Hero". But after downloading when i open workspace it says can not convert swift 2 to 3 in xcode 9.

Answer (score 2):

Okay found the solution.
In the first case where I have:

```
@IBAction func handleButton() {
  let view = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondVC") as! UIViewController
  present(view, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I have to set the animation there on the view.

```
@IBAction func handleButton() {
  let view = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondVC") as! UIViewController
  view.hero.modalAnimationType = .push(direction: .right)
  present(view, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

works

Comment: view.hero.modalAnimation will only work for view in ViewController What to do when we are presenting a vC from a Table cell?

Answer (score 0):

Set the modal animation type by setting the Hero extension `heroModalAnimationType`:

```
hero.heroModalAnimationType = .push(direction: .right)
```

Don't forget to disable the default animation for the transition using the `Hero.shared` object's methods :

```
func disableDefaultAnimationForNextTransition()
func setDefaultAnimationForNextTransition(_ animation: HeroDefaultAnimationType)
```

Comment: It´s set on both view controllers.

Comment: Yeah I edited the post to show the full. How do I disable the default animation with Hero.shared?

Comment: Hey @Carpsen90, I don't see a method `disableDefaultAnimationForNextTransition()` on `Hero.shared`... can you tell me where this is?

Comment: PS - I found `Hero.shared.defaultAnimation = .none` for Swift 4.